# Wondering.. If mysql and mysqli could be possibly used in the same website all at once?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to connect everything? the end-users uses mysql and the admin uses mysqli? In which for the end users I'll be using the mysql for displaying the contents for them to see and mysqli for my admin account?

Comment: I don't think your supposed to use mysql anymore, which was replaced by the more secure mysqli.

Comment: @Bartdude, I agree with you but migrating such codes to mysqli_* wasn't that easy though based on my own experience.=)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, these are two completely independent APIs and you can establish any number of simultaneous connections to your database using one or both APIs at the same time. No, this makes absolutely no sense to do in the real world, since there's no benefit for doing so at all.

Comment: You can also use two (or more) mysqli connections or two PDO connections at the same time. But it still makes no sense to actually do it that way, it only makes sense if you need to access two completely different databases in the same script.

Comment: But it makes sense if you're migrating your code component by component from mysql to mysqli IMO. The final goal is to move everything to mysqli but nobody forces you to make this migration in one step.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` is depreciated. `mysqli` is the replacment. You should use `mysqli` for all connections in the future.

`mysqli` is designed to utilise features is MySQL 4.1 and above, and has superior security (if you ultilise the features made available). I would advise upgrading your end user experience to use `mysqli`.

However, to answer your question, **Yes, you could use both types of connection!**

Check out the php.net to learn about mysqli and its implementations.

[The mysqli extension - php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)

Comment: "Superior security" *if you know how to use it*. It's trivial to write the same crap code using mysqli that you can write using mysql. :)

Comment: Hi Deceze, Thats very true, thats why i suggested learning about mysqli on php.net. That way MysEager can utilise mysqli either procedurally or object oriented, and increase the security using mysqli methods to prepare statements before they are inserted. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @deceze, Sorry but that is same comment used to hide problem of software again and again. If one of two software provide more inbuilt functionality regarding security then their should not be any execuse to use other piece of software just for legacy.

Comment: @kuldeep I don't understand what you're trying to say. Of course you should be using the API that offers more security features if given the choice. I just want to make explicit that this security doesn't come for free. Just replacing `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$_POST[name]'")` with the equivalent mysqli call won't do anything for security.

Comment: Yes, So prepared statement were introduced. In plane mysql no such things exists. So yes anybody can write unsecure code in mysqli. But still atleast we have builtin/recommended way to ignore them.